# How to increase Maximum number of steps in any other functions except NDSolve?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, differential-equations, control-systems

I want to plot an output response from a state space model. I use `StateResponse[]` to calculate it and then plot it. When I run my code, I face this message:

> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 0.007796405242565201`.

I do not even use `NDSolve[]` command to solve my equations!
This is my code and its answer:

`u = -kk.StateResponse[ssmModelC, 
     UnitStep[t] , {t, 0, 10}]`

How is it possible to increase number of steps in  `StateResponse[]`?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example?

Comment: @ Rod LM :I edited my post and give an example. Hope you find it useful!

Comment: @user8364 But you forgot to put your definition for `ssmModelC`... the code is still not working.

Comment: @ Rod LM : Actually, `ssmModelC` is a 120*120 Matrix and 3 more huge matrixes, which build my space state model, and I can not put them here! The point is Maximum steps to calculate the response between 0 and 10 seconds! I have no idea to increase the number of steps!

Comment: This option would work Method -> {"NDSolve", MaxSteps -> value}, although undocumented.

Comment: @suba you could provide that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MaxSteps` option (or any other option to `NDSolve`) can be adjusted by specifying it as a suboption.

```
u = -kk.StateResponse[ssmModelC, UnitStep[t] , {t, 0, 10}, Method -> {"NDSolve", MaxSteps -> value}]
```

The only caveat is that it is not yet documented.

And regarding when `NDSolve` is used, pretty much when there is a continuous-time system and the time specification is of the form $\{t, tmin, tmax\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is absolutely perfect!